# Is there a way to select real object from a proxy with AlpineJS?

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

Is there a way to select the real object from a proxy in Vue you can use `toRaw` is there something similar in AlpineJS?

I am using PDF.js and I am assigning the `pdf_` to the `pdfInstance` in createPdf but when I access it in render page instead of any object its a proxy so I cannot call any object method on that like `getPage`. If i do i get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read from private field`.

```
 createPdf() {
        PDFJS.getDocument(option.url).promise.then(pdf_ => {
            console.log("PDF === ", pdf_);
            this.pdfInstance = pdf_;
            this.renderPage();
        });
    },
renderPage() {

        console.log("PDF INSTANCE ===", this.pdfInstance);
}
```

[image]